# java.lang.SecurityException: Requires MANAGE_APP_TOKENS permission when i use facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, permissions, facebook-sdk-4.x

When we use the Facebook SDK to our app, but some user occur this problem, what is the problem with it?

[image]

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires MANAGE_APP_TOKENS permission
 at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
 at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
 at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3503)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5062)
 at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2737)
 at

Comment: you can see the detail in the image as above